unable to sell token despite seeing other wallets selling
I bought this token on base network and the contract looks perfect to me, but i realize i was unable to sell/swap the token after increasing the slippage to 50%, i can see other wallets selling and i tried other dex too but it's seems the token is unsellable. i guess it's a scam but if anyone could help explain where in the contract is the code causing the issue, I'd be eternally grateful. i know i won't be able to get the funds out, but I would at least like to be able to spot this code from now on.
Here is the contract for "STEVE"
https://basescan.org/address/0x2505B8c4B2A98E42656a6650aaa5243958e0A0d4
thanks in advance for reading and your help!

Can you provide more details? like a failed transaction. The code has some oddities, but they doesn't seem malicious by themselves.
